# A question whether this is the correct result or not

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I have to solve this definite integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{\cosh(x)-1})dx $$

So in the solution I found in a textbook(I know I should've just solved it on my own):

It was this solution:
 Substitution: 
$$ t= \sqrt{\cosh x-1} , dx=?= \frac{2}{\sqrt{ t^2 +2}} dt$$

And then it went to the result: $4(\cosh1+1)-\sqrt2$

But I got a different result when checking it in Wolfram Alpha.
I am confused with how the substitution was defined; I mean, was the $dx$ correctly rewritten.

I would appreciate any help,

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make the substitution $u \mapsto \cosh(x)$ and $du = \sinh(x)\,dx$

\begin{align*}
I &= \int \sqrt{\cosh x - 1} \,dx \\
&= -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u+1}} \, du \\
&= -2 \sqrt{u+1} \\
&= -2 \sqrt{\cosh x + 1} + c
\end{align*}

Now the definite integral,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\cosh x - 1}\,dx &= \left[ -2\sqrt{\cosh x + 1} \right]_0^1 \\
&= -2 (\sqrt{\cosh 1 +1 } - \sqrt{\cosh 0 +1}) \\
&= -2 \sqrt{\cosh 1 + 1} + 2\sqrt{2} \\
\end{align*}

**Another (*easier*) Method:**

Using [hyperbolic half-argument identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Half_argument_formulas) we can transform the integral into,

$$ \sqrt{2} \int \sinh \frac{x}{2}\,dx $$

which is fairly simple to evaluate using the chain rule,

$$ 2\sqrt{2} \cosh \frac{x}{2} + c $$

and you get $2\sqrt{2} (\cosh \frac{1}{2} - 1)$, which is equivalent to above.

Comment: So the textbook one was wrong as i thought

Comment: yes numerically the textbook was off